# Is there an equivalent to Python's 'in' keyword for c++?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write my c++ code more clearly and compactly, so let's say I'm trying to avoid statements like:

```
if(MIN_VALUE <= a && a <= MAX_VALUE)
```

and replace it with something similar to:

```
if(a in [MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE])
```

Comment: For the record, `a in [MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE]` is not at all the same as `MIN_VALUE <= a and a <= MAX_VALUE` in Python. It's `a == MIN_VALUE or a == MAX_VALUE`. So your question starts from a false premise to begin with.

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: Assuming that 2nd piece of code is python, it doesn't have the same meaning as your C++ code. It's equivalent to `if (a == MIN_VALUE || a == MAX_VALUE)`

Comment: You could probably simulate this but it will be a barrier to entry for other people that use your code as they will have to learn it.  The stock `if(MIN_VALUE <= a && a <= MAX_VALUE)` on the other hand is clear to all.

Comment: *I'm trying to write my c++ code more clearly and compactly* -- To another C++ programmer, your version of "clear and compact" will look just weird.  Just write C++ as C++, not as another language.

Comment: Clear code and compact code do not go hand in hand. More compact code is not always cleaner code. Expressive code is clear, and it's not always compact.

Comment: In Python, you would want to do an interval comparison `if MIN_VALUE <= a <= MAX_VALUE:` and the first example is closest way to do the same thing in C++ (in my opinion).  C++ does not have interval comparison.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [`std::clamp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp) which, unlike most STL functions, returns values in the closed interval `[lo, hi]`:

```
if (v == std::clamp(v, lo, hi)) {
    // lo <= v && v <= hi.
}
```

Comment: Oops. My apologies for trolling your answer. +1 for good feelings!

Comment: I really like this.  I had to look it up to confirm the interval (which really isn't a big deal), but I really like it.

Answer (score 7):

No there isn't but you could build one yourself:

```
template <typename T>
bool in(const T& a, const T& low, const T& high) 
{ 
    return a - low <= high - low; 
}
```

Comment: I'll build you.